# Using spring:nestedPath tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this code, I know I'm missing something but don't know what. It would be great if you help me out. I'm new to Spring MVC.

I'm trying out a simple Login application in Spring MVC.

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

here is my springapp-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
 <bean name="/login" class="springapp.web.LoginController"/>
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
 <bean id="employee" class="springapp.domain.Employee" />
</beans>
```

Here is my LoginController.java file

```
package springapp.web;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import springapp.domain.Employee;

public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController{

  public LoginController(){
    setCommandName("loginEmployee");
    setCommandClass(Employee.class);
    setFormView("login");
    setSuccessView("welcome");
  }
@Override
  protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
    return super.onSubmit(command);
  }
}
```

And finally my login.jsp file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Timesheet Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<spring:nestedPath path="employee">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table width="200" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
                <td>
                    <spring:bind path="userName">
                        <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" id="${status.value}" />
                    </spring:bind>
                </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>
                <spring:bind path="password">
                    <input type="password" name="${status.expression}" id="${status.value}" />
                </spring:bind>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</spring:nestedPath>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to run the code I get this error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'employee' available as request attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `commandName` is `loginEmployee`, not `employee`

Answer (score 1):

I got it...
I didn't use the command name that I defined in the controller. aaaaahhhhh...HUH.... Sorry for the post.  :(

changed this 
    setCommandName("loginEmployee");
to 
    setCommandName("employee");